# Why does adding additional search constraints increases the number of results returned by the YouTube search API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm attempting to perform analytics on the popularity of a subject as measured by "YouTube Videos Over Time". I'm querying via Python using a slightly modified version of the example code Google provides: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#usage

```
search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part='id,snippet',
    maxResults=options.max_results,
    type='video',
    order='date',
    publishedAfter='2016-12-06T00:00:00.000Z',
    publishedBefore='2016-12-06T23:59:59.000Z'
).execute()
```

When I query on "destiny" I get back 7 results, all of which contain "destiny" in the title (reformatted for readability):

```
2016-12-06T21:30:00.000Z    vYBcfTleK9k Do Females Have A Smaller Hitbox Than Males In Destiny & MORE! (Destiny Mythbusters)    SUBSCRIBE To Help Reach 100K: (Here Are Some More Destiny Videos You May Enjoy) ▻Destiny MYTHBUSTERS! - HOW MANY ...
2016-12-06T21:05:42.000Z    bDpLQNlLuec Destiny: Trials of Osiris - 1v3 (31-3) vs. Teabaggers on Widows Court   Twitch VOD - https://www.twitch.tv/itskruzer/v/105609493 Thanks to everyone who came to the stream! It was a memorable one. I was most successful using my ...
2016-12-06T19:50:40.000Z    mbJYCfq0Sb0 Destiny Syharaj: The Power to be a Leader   Winooski High School student, Destiny Syharaj, talks about how her school gave her the power to be a leader.
2016-12-06T18:57:01.000Z    Zd2MwAANOvA Destiny - NEW Last Word Exotic Ornaments Addendum And Sequel!   Leave a like if you enjoyed! Destiny - NEW Last Word Exotic Ornaments Addendum And Sequel! ▻Want Thumb And Controller Grips? Check Out Fatal Grips ...
2016-12-06T17:44:55.000Z    ZhLfbmzsivo [DESTINY] OBTENIR LE BRISE GLACE ANNÉE 3 -  REVIEW ARME EXOTIQUE    Tu as aimé cette vidéo ? Alors abonne toi ici : http://urlz.fr/rv6 ☆ ⇓ Open Me ⇓ ╔══════════════════╗ ☆ Enjoy, Life Is Just A Game...
2016-12-06T02:52:35.000Z    l6xXjg5zRCE Destiny Glitches - Who Is This Wizard In Crucible?  A crucible glitch to go try out if you're bored one day looking for something to entertain you. A smaller YouTuber that goes by Swagmcnugget found this glitch.
2016-12-06T00:25:39.000Z    2uMVRqRX7aQ Destiny - Misprinted Dice   What to expect from FFG Customer Support if you have any misprinted dice or defective products with Star Wars Destiny, or any other game. The official policy: ...
```

When I query on "destiny epic" I get back *12* results, all of which contain "destiny" in the title as well:

```
2016-12-06T23:07:44.000Z    s7BLOxvRm98 Epic Montage/Destiny    https://www.facebook.com/Ciberoso-137782546385392/?fref=ts.
2016-12-06T20:15:03.000Z    2dx0GqfH3D4 RAGE and FURY - A Destiny Clantage from Niederroler This is our new clantage from G4A Editor: SOADASSASSIN Cast: AUT_RONIN_ EDLIN_11 XX_RUSHER_1_XX DEATHMATCHER11 MADEINTIROL91 ...
2016-12-06T19:59:45.000Z    79X3m_gbKTA Destiny iron banner event   hey whats up guys its delta here aka kirito bringing you some epic gaming moments with my friends or by my self.
2016-12-06T19:57:47.000Z    EmaSG1AXX9Y Destiny highlights #1   Destiny epic montage.
2016-12-06T18:59:01.000Z    bsRgKJt7EU0 Cruzible Party - A destiny Montage  Musik: Dan Bull epic Destiny Rap Sorry for not having a sound Tommorow it will have.
2016-12-06T18:44:16.000Z    Gkut448qBv4 Destiny Epic Clincher Match A Destiny Match!!! A very close one that is, me and the team i'm on go head to head with the other team and our opponents are always at least just a few points ...
2016-12-06T18:13:58.000Z    pcc05A5qqaI Halo vs Destiny Rap Battle - By Ninethie And Random Pigeon Ft. Ashleigh Longest title ever, but eh... I need something long in my lif- Wait... That isn't right. Let me know what you all thought, it's pretty trashy I know, so enjoy I guess?
2016-12-06T17:39:47.000Z    VKXmVvunHs4 Destiny Epic Mayhem Rumble skill    Sit back relax and enjoy 8mins of sick and epic skill and luck of yours truly N0VA_R3D_.
2016-12-06T07:38:49.000Z    DNDUmX0Ann0 Destiny's Rift Epic win pt1 With the right team anythings possible SHAREfactory™ https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/tid=CUSA00572_00.
2016-12-06T05:07:30.000Z    eEaelP5vP3Y Tis thy #Classic ROCK Destiny, So thy Epic A??  Hey youtube Viewers, wats up. Welcome to my channel of games... i hope you like wat you see. you can always message me in game, i would like to say this, if u ...
2016-12-06T03:59:05.000Z    mxwx5sigVpY Destiny Epic Trickshot
2016-12-06T03:36:28.000Z    qOQxp6S-1JE Destiny PvP Crucible Highlights #1  Hey guys this is footage i gathered playing destiny. There are epic sniper gameplay and a over all good crucibe Highlights. you well see my sniper the 1000 yard ...
```

What's going on here? Why are the "destiny epic" videos not returned via the more parsimonious "destiny" query?